# Распознавание введенного текста

Tags: java, строки

Хочу сделать, чтобы после введения пользователем определенного текста, выполнялся код. Но почему-то в конструкции if else, всегда выполняется сразу часть else?

```
System.out.println("Напиши слово \"комманда\", чтобы узнать, что я умею");
Scanner cmd = new Scanner(System.in);
String cmd1 = cmd.next();
if (cmd1 == "комманда") {
    System.out.println("1.. 2.. 3...");
}
else System.out.println("Пока.");
```

Comment: Строки в Java нужно сравнивать через equals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Строки в Java нужно сравнивать через `equals`. Сравнение через `==` проверяет ссылки, а не сами значения в строках.

   ```
   cmd1.equals("комманда")
   ```

   или

   ```
   Objects.equals(cmd1, "комманда")
   ```
2. В вашем случае лучше подойдёт `switch`:

   ```
   switch(cmd1) {
       case "комманда":
           System.out.println("1.. 2.. 3...");
           break;
       default:
           System.out.println("Пока.");
           break;
   }
   ```